# what is the equilvalent of -webkit-focus-ring-color for chrome

Tags: html, css

I have the following styles in my css file:

```
    input[type="file"]:focus,
    input[type="radio"]:focus,
    input[type="checkbox"]:focus {
      outline: none;
      outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color(hack in chrome);
      border: 1px dotted transparent !important;
      outline-color : #1fbf81;
      outline-offset: -2px;
    }
```

Using the  above style especially with  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color(hack in chrome) im able to style radio button with green border in chrome, however in firefox Im getting white dotted border.May I know how I can remove the white border and have green in firefox as well.Do I need to have any hack for firefox if so, please let me know.

Thanks,
Balaji

Answer (score 0):

Try to give as outline:0px !important;

Answer (score -1):

-webkit = Chrome and Safari

-moz = FireFox

-o = Opera

-ms = Internet Explorer

So:

```
    outline: 5px auto -moz-focus-ring-color(hack in chrome);
```

Comment: Hi, I have done that, it is working fine, but still im not able to remove the dotted white line around radio button in firefox, any idea, anyways thanks for your help

Comment: How about: `outline-style: none; -moz-outline-style:none;`

Comment: Tried the above two steps somehow Im still getting the white dotted line in firefox, thanks Stefan